# How to achieve this json in POST request react?

Tags: reactjs

I have this POST request:

```
await fetch('http://localhost:8080/api/order', {
      method: 'POST',
      body: JSON.stringify({
      orderNumber: 1,
      customer: {customerId:1},
      orderDetails: cartCtx.items,
      pmethod: "karta",
}
```

but can you achieve JSON like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WDK3q.png)? The problem is with `orderDetails` because i dont know how to group my `cartCtx.items array` like in the picture. Any ideas?

This is my [array](https://i.stack.imgur.com/buQua.png).

Comment: We need to see an example of `cartCtx.items` to help you here.

Comment: I edited post. Is this enough information?

Comment: @M3zuss Please post text here directly, not a screenshot.

Comment: @M3zuss can you please post the JSON inline instead of a link to an image?

Comment: Thats how my JSON is right now. {"orderNumber":1,"customer":{"customerId":1},"orderDetails":[{"foodItemId":"0","quantity":1},{"foodItemId":"1","quantity":1}],"pmethod":"karta"}

Comment: @M3zuss Can you see how your current JSON differs from what you want? You just need to do a little more work to get the shapes to match.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice basically my orderDetails is an array and inside this array i want to have an additional group of foodItem for my foodItemId but quantity have to be outside this additional field. If i do something like this : `orderDetails: {foodItem:cartCtx.items}` both id and quantity are inside this foodItem.

Answer (score 0):

> basically my orderDetails is an array and inside this array i want to have an additional group of foodItem for my foodItemId but quantity have to be outside this additional field. If i do something like this : `orderDetails: {foodItem:cartCtx.items}` both id and quantity are inside this foodItem

You are on the right track. The `orderDetails` list needs a list of objects which each have a `"foodItem"` key. One way create an array of objects with this key is to use `map()`:

```
cartCtx.items.map(item => {foodItem: item})
```

This creates a new array with the required key and each of the original items nested inside.

Comment: `cartCtx.items.map(item => ({foodItem: item}))` this will work. Sorry for failed post I misunderstood the problem first.

Comment: @DánielBoros No problem. Thank you for contributing!

Comment: So if i want to have only one field of an array with this new key and rest without it. I cant?

Comment: @M3zuss Most likely you can. However, you need to be more careful in your wording and thinking. What do you mean by "only one field of an array with this new key"? Arrays don't have "fields". They have "elements". You can definitely create an array of objects where one of the objects has the `"foodItem"` key and none of the others do. However, that probably won't work for your POST request.

Comment: @M3zuss Also, you should consider building `cartCtx.items` from the beginning in the way you need for the POST request. Then you won't have to transform it like this.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice yes i know, but seems like i forgot about this one thing and now i wanted to ask if there is a possible to not change everything and do it "around". Sorry for my bad wording.